# How to add a light to a 3d scene in Qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I am developing an application with a cube with 6 different textures in QML.

I made the cube pattern with Blender and attached the texture to the model I created and saved.

But I have a small problem, the textures load correctly but I have shadows that appear and darken the different sides of the cube.

Does anyone have an idea how to remove these shadows?

I put below the code of my application and a screenshot of what I get as a result.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12



Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Scene3D
    {
        id : scene3d
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: false
        aspects: ["render", "logic", "input"]
        hoverEnabled: true
        cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio

        RootEntity
        {
            id:root
        }

    }

}
```

**SOrbitCamera.qml**

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0

Entity{
    id: root
    property Camera camera;
    property real dt: 0.001
    property real linearSpeed: 1
    property real lookSpeed: 500

    MouseDevice {
        id: mouseDevice
        sensitivity: 0.007
    }

    MouseHandler {
        id: mh
        property vector3d upVect: Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0)
        property point lastPos;
        property real pan;
        property real tilt;
        sourceDevice: mouseDevice

        onPanChanged: {

            if (camera.position.y < 0.5 && camera.position.y > -3.) {
                root.camera.panAboutViewCenter(-pan, upVect);
            }

            if (camera.position.y > 0.5 && camera.position.y < 3.) {
                root.camera.panAboutViewCenter(pan, upVect);
            }

            if (camera.position.y < 6. && camera.position.y > 3.) {
                root.camera.panAboutViewCenter(-pan, upVect);

            }

            if (camera.position.y > -6. && camera.position.y < -3.) {
                root.camera.panAboutViewCenter(pan, upVect);

            }

        }

        onTiltChanged: root.camera.tiltAboutViewCenter(tilt);

        onPressed: {
            lastPos = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        }

        onPositionChanged: {
            if (mouse.buttons === 1){ // Left button for rotation

                pan = -(mouse.x - lastPos.x) * dt * lookSpeed;
                tilt = (mouse.y - lastPos.y) * dt * lookSpeed;
                console.log(camera.position)
            }

            lastPos = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)
        }
    }
}
```

**RootEntity.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick3D 1.15
import Qt3D.Core 2.12
import Qt3D.Render 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.12
import Qt3D.Input 2.12





Entity {
    id: root


    //create camera

    Camera {
        id: mainCamera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: 16/9
        nearPlane : 0.1
        farPlane : 1000.0
        position: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 4.49373, -3.78577)
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: cubeTransform.translation
    }

    //use my class instead of OrbitCameraController

    SOrbitCameraController {
        id: mainCameraController
        camera: mainCamera
    }

    components: [
        RenderSettings {

            Viewport {
                normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                RenderSurfaceSelector {
                    CameraSelector {
                        id: cameraSelector
                        camera: mainCamera
                        FrustumCulling {
                            ClearBuffers {
                                buffers: ClearBuffers.AllBuffers
                                clearColor: "black"
                                NoDraw {}
                            }
                            LayerFilter {
                                filterMode: LayerFilter.DiscardAnyMatchingLayers
                                layers: [topLayer]
                            }
                            LayerFilter {
                                filterMode: LayerFilter.AcceptAnyMatchingLayers
                                layers: [topLayer]
                                ClearBuffers {
                                    buffers: ClearBuffers.DepthBuffer
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        InputSettings {}
        ,
        ScreenRayCaster
        {
            id:screenRayCaster
            onHitsChanged:
            {
                drawLineMesh(hits)

            }
        }
    ]

    Layer {
        id: topLayer
        recursive: true
    }

    Entity {
            id: cubeEntity

            Texture2D {
                id:texture
                TextureImage {
                    source: "qrc:/../Downloads/texture.png"
                }
            }

            Mesh {
                id: cubeMesh
                source: "qrc:/../Downloads/cube.obj"
            }


            Transform {
                id: cubeTransform
                translation: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
            }


            NormalDiffuseMapMaterial{
                id: material
                normal: texture
                diffuse: texture
                specular: texture
            }

            components: [cubeMesh, cubeTransform, material]

    }

}
```

[image: output]

[image: cube pattern]

Comment: I think it's not because of shadow, it's for lack of enough light. You should add some light source and it will be fix.

Comment: Hi Farshid, thank you for your answer, i'm a bit new in 3D, if you can give me some explanation about light and how to use it, it will help me a lot

Comment: Checkout this link https://forum.qt.io/topic/71378/how-can-i-add-a-light-to-my-scene3d/3 , and for a complete example with more details you can see the official lights example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick3d-lights-example.html

Comment: I add the light but I have another problem. On each face of the cube, the texture is separate in 2. One part is visible and the other not

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of it? Maybe it's because that you just add one light. You should add multiple lights from different directions or adding an ibl https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quick3d-asset-conditioning-ibl.html but at this moment focus on multiple light source

Comment: Yes I will add it, sorry I'm really bad with 3D, materials, ... etc

Comment: Use edit feature to edit your question and adding some stuff and avoiding to creating an answer to add some information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I add the following code in **RootEntity.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick3D 1.15
import Qt3D.Core 2.12
import Qt3D.Render 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.12
import Qt3D.Input 2.12

import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.12





Entity {
    id: root

    Entity {
        id: lightEntity
        components: [
        DirectionalLight{
            intensity: 0.5
            enabled: true
        },
        Transform{
                translation: Qt.vector3d(0,50,0)
          }
         ]
    }


    //create camera

    Camera {
        id: mainCamera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: 16/9
        nearPlane : 0.1
        farPlane : 1000.0
        position: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 4.49373, -3.78577)
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: cubeTransform.translation
    }


    SOrbitCameraController {
        id: mainCameraController
        camera: mainCamera
    }

    components: [
        RenderSettings {

            Viewport {
                normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                RenderSurfaceSelector {
                    CameraSelector {
                        id: cameraSelector
                        camera: mainCamera
                        FrustumCulling {
                            ClearBuffers {
                                buffers: ClearBuffers.AllBuffers
                                clearColor: "black"
                                NoDraw {}
                            }
                            LayerFilter {
                                filterMode: LayerFilter.DiscardAnyMatchingLayers
                                layers: [topLayer]
                            }
                            LayerFilter {
                                filterMode: LayerFilter.AcceptAnyMatchingLayers
                                layers: [topLayer]
                                ClearBuffers {
                                    buffers: ClearBuffers.DepthBuffer
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        },
        InputSettings {}
    ]

    Layer {
        id: topLayer
        recursive: true
    }



    /*
    CuboidMesh{
        id: cubeMesh

        xExtent: 1
        yExtent: 1
        zExtent: 1
    }*/







    Entity {
            id: cubeEntity

            Texture2D {
                id:texture
                TextureImage {
                    source: "qrc:/../Downloads/texture.png"
                }
            }

            Mesh {
                id: cubeMesh
                source: "qrc:/../Downloads/cube.obj"
            }


            Transform {
                id: cubeTransform
                translation: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
            }


            NormalDiffuseMapMaterial{
                id: material
                normal: texture
                diffuse: texture
            }

            components: [cubeMesh, cubeTransform, material]

    }

}
```

I have the following result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define some light source for your scene.
These are some example for Directional and Point lights:

```
DirectionalLight {
    id: directionalLight
    x: -0
    y: 828.821
    color: "#e0eef0"
    shadowMapQuality: Light.ShadowMapQualityMedium
    shadowFactor: 58
    castsShadow: true
    eulerRotation.z: 43.68403
    eulerRotation.y: -57.35873
    eulerRotation.x: -35.78494
    z: 1415.04834
    brightness: 80
}

PointLight {
    id: lightPoint
    x: -7.983
    y: 737.434
    shadowFactor: 4
    castsShadow: true
    brightness: 122
    quadraticFade: 0.19392
    z: 108.31305
}
```

You can move your lights or rotate the lights direction with changing the x, y and defining rotation values.

Comment: I add a DirectionnalLight to my program and I have this behavior now, it's almost what I want